# combining multiple CCSprites into one grouped object in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I wonder what's the best approach to combine several CCSprites dynamically into one grouped object using cocos2d.

I have to dynamically create characters from a set of multiple CCSprites. The elements can't move relative to each other after combined - and are never separated again.

When combined they should behave just like one CCSprite in terms of moving and turning etc.

I couldn't find anything in cocos2d, or do I have to use a physics engine just to achieve this? I am afraid, using Box2d (without experience) creates a lot of additional coding overhead and effort.

Many thanks

Comment: since I didn't find any build in solution I created a new combined object myself which takes care of combining the sprites into one object - this actually wasn't to complicated and still provides some important advantages...

Comment: Just add them to a CCLayer ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create an empty CCSprite and add the body parts from different sprites. Example:

```
CCSprite *body = [CCSprite node];
CCSprite *arm = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"arm.png"];
[arm setPosition:CGPointMake(10,10)];

[body addChild:arm];
```

And so on. This way you can rotate the sprite named *body* and all body parts will adjust accordingly.

Comment: wow, thats exactly what I was looking for and then programmed on my own since I did nit know otherways Thanks!

Comment: How can I conver this line to c++ : CCSprite *body = [CCSprite node]; I am getting following error : 'node' is not a member of 'cocos2d::CCSprite'

Comment: Well @eric but the problem is that the content size of the parent sprite is 0.0*0.0.Is there any way to get the mid point of height as well as width  of the complex CCSprite node directly from its position and content size?