# How to add multiple images to a single sprite in cocos2d?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am creating an application in `cocos2d` using `sprite builder` where a user clicks a picture from the camera which is then converted into a jigsaw puzzle. I have cropped and converted the image into a puzzle of four images by masking and saved it into an array successfully. I now want to add all the four images into the same sprite. At the moment I'm adding the images to the sprite with a `for loop` but I end up overwriting the previous images and the end result is a single image in the sprite. I'm not sure how to add multiple images to the sprite (or multiple sprites to the screen. Whichever works). Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards codePassion.

Comment: you cant.  A CCSprite is associated to a single texture. You could however have a CCNode in which you add N CCSprites, each CCSprite having been initialized with a single texture.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554639/combining-multiple-ccsprites-into-one-grouped-object-in-cocos2d) the solution?

Comment: you could do that ... i like to have CCNodes as 'containers', there are many benefits. But as per the post, if you add sprite 2, 3, and 4 to sprite 1 would work too. After all sprite 1 is an extension of CCNode. But ... in my world, i dont use sprites for anything other than texture containers. My object model use CCNode as the mother of all object instances.

Comment: I need to think this thing through as the user need to rearrange the puzzle pieces too. So my next question is that is there a way that user can drag around sprite so that he can solve the puzzle?